Unity2D animation problem, Jumping/Falling Animation
I was following a youtuber called antarsoft on his tutorial for 2d movement and animations, i got to the jumping animation part, I did everything he said but when I jump. The animations are playing weirdly, I've been trying to research ways to fix it but I cannot find any fixes, I saw a similar post to mine but their solution wasn't inline with my code or had nothing to do with it.
I've tried taking them off loop but that just makes them do no animation, I havn't tried anything else as I cant find any solutions anywhere or any guides.
Video: How the problem looks
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float groundCheckRadius = 0.2f;
    const float overheadCheckRadius = 0.2f;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 1;
    [SerializeField] float jumpPower = 65;

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator animator;
    [SerializeField]Collider2D standingCollider;

    [SerializeField] Transform groundCheckCollider;
    [SerializeField] Transform overheadCheckCollider;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask groundLayer; 

    float horizontalValue;
    float runSpeedModifier = 2f;
    float crouchSpeedModifier = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] bool isGrounded;
    bool jump;
    [SerializeField] bool crouchPressed;
    bool isRunning;
    bool facingRight = true;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        //Set they yVelocity in the animator
        animator.SetFloat("yVelocity", rb.velocity.y);

        horizontalValue = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        isRunning = true;
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        isRunning = false;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("Jump", true);
        }
        else if(Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
        jump = false;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        isRunning = true;
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        isRunning = false;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        crouchPressed = true;
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        crouchPressed = false;



    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GroundCheck();
        Move(horizontalValue, jump, crouchPressed);
    }

    void GroundCheck()
    {
        isGrounded = false;

        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheckCollider.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
        if (colliders.Length > 0)   
        isGrounded = true;

        animator.SetBool("Jump", !isGrounded);
    }

    void Move(float dir,bool jumpFlag,bool crouchFlag)
    {
        #region jump and crouch

        if (!crouchFlag)
        {
            if (Physics2D.OverlapCircle(overheadCheckCollider.position,overheadCheckRadius,groundLayer))
            crouchFlag = true;

        }

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            standingCollider.enabled = !crouchFlag;



            //If the player is grounded press space to jump
            if (jumpFlag)
            {
                //isGrounded = false;
                jumpFlag = false;
                //Add jump force    
                rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpPower));
            }

        }

        animator.SetBool("Crouch", crouchFlag);

        #endregion
        #region move and run
        //Set value of x using dir and speed
        float xVal = dir * speed * 100 * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        if (isRunning)
        xVal *= runSpeedModifier;

        if (crouchFlag)
        xVal *= crouchSpeedModifier;
        //Create Vec2 for the Velocity
        Vector2 targetVelocity = new Vector2(xVal, rb.velocity.y);
        //Set the players Velocity
        rb.velocity = targetVelocity;

        //If looking right and press left, turn left
        if (facingRight && dir < 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x * -1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
            facingRight = false;
        }
        //If looking left and press right, turn to the right
        else if (!facingRight && dir > 0)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(transform.localScale.x * -1, transform.localScale.y, transform.localScale.z);
            facingRight = true;
        }

        Debug.Log(rb.velocity.x);
        animator.SetFloat("xVelocity", Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x));
        #endregion
    }
}


well i probably wouldnt make jump false until it landed..  and i also wouldnt set jump animation until you actually told it to jump ..  it also might vary with your animator, so for example, it looks like hes running in the air which looks likely given the code.

I don't get what you mean

im not sure how much better to explain it, given it is your code :P
